# pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame, xcode, visual-studio-code

I don't know what's going on when I try to run pygame this error occures everytime no matter how much changes I have made.

**HERE'S THE CODE:**

```
import pygame
import tine
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dodgers")

def main():
    run = True

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break

pygame.quit()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How have you tried applying [previous answers about this particular error message](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=video+system+initialized+)?